# How to use @Assert\Type(Class / Interface)

Tags: php, symfony

I'm trying to use @Assert\Type of Symfony (5.1) with an Interface as validation. Here is my attribut I'm trying to validate:

```
 /**
  *
  * @Assert\Type(type="Eldotravo\Entity\UtmData")
  * @Assert\Valid()
  */
 private $utmData;
```

Here is my Entity to validate utmData:

```
namespace Eldotravo\Entity;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 */
class UtmData
{
    /**
     * @Assert\Type(type="string")
     */
    private $test;
}
```

It seems that Symfony is not even trying to access my entity class to valid my Type.
As the documentation is mentioning it's possible
https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Type.html#reference-constraint-type-type
and
https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/embedded.html#embedding-a-single-object

Here is what I get as a response from API plateforme:

```
{
"@context": "/api/v2/contexts/ConstraintViolationList",
"@type": "ConstraintViolationList",
"hydra:title": "An error occurred",
"hydra:description": "utmData: This Value should be a type of Eldotravo\\Entity\\UtmData.",
"violations": [
    {
        "propertyPath": "utmData",
        "message": "This Value should be a type of Eldotravo\\Entity\\UtmData."
    }
]
```

}

Does anyone as an input for this problem? Documentation seems really poor and not many threads are talking about it...

EDIT: I'm sending a correct object and getting this response back.

Comment: Are you saying that this validation error triggers even when the property is assigned an object of the correct type?

Comment: That's right, I forgot to mention it, but I'm sending a correct object and I'm getting this response back.

Comment: Have you tried testing it directly, in a page (without the API)? That would narrow the issue down to either being a) somewhere internally in Symfony while processing the request or b) Symfony and API Platform working together.

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? Have you properly imported that class `Eldotravo\Entity\UtmData`? Even if the validator is a bit clumsy to debug, it should not be impossible to run the request using XDebug to check what happens inside the validator

Comment: @El_Vanja I will try it.
unfortunately Xdebug is being a bit hard to run with Docker. That's also work in progress.

In the end I might move to build a Custom Constraint even if that's definitely not the cleanest. Thanks for your help guys